# SQL Server Dense Rank in reverse order

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

I have 3 columns, they are created by Dense Rank, Count, and Row Number

DR  C   RN 
1    4     1
2    4    2
3    4     3
4    4     4

Is there any way for the DENSE_RANK or some other ranking function return in reverse order?

Like this

DR  C   RN
4    4     1
3    4     2
2    4     3
1    4     4

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

try this. Use `order by RN desc` in `dense rank` `over clause`

```
SELECT Dense_rank () OVER (partition BY c ORDER BY rn DESC) DN,
       *
FROM  (SELECT 4 C,1 RN
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 4,2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 4,3
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 4,4) A
ORDER  BY dn DESC
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
DN  C   RN
--  --  --
4   4   1
3   4   2
2   4   3
1   4   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Work like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

you should use DESC in dense_rank

```
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.t1 ORDER BY (t.t2) DESC) DENSE_RANK
```

Comment: This question was already answered to that effect 9 years ago